# \command[]{} or \command{}[]?

Tags: parameters

Sometimes I see `[]` before `{}`, such as:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
```

Sometimes I see `{}` before `[]`, such as:

```
\newcommand{name}[num]{definition}
```

Which should go first, `[]` or `{}` ? Does it matter?

Comment: It depends very much on the command and yes, order *does* matter.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). The normal style is the have the optional parameters (using the `[]`) first followed by all the mandatory parameters (using the `{}`).  But this can be changed (see for example the `xparse` pacakge).  So, for your own macros stick to defining the optional paramters first followed by the mandatory ones, unless there is a very good reason to do otherwise. For exisitng macros, you would need to consult the documentation as to the required order.

Comment: In case you were wondering, this is typically implemented using `\@ifnextchar[{\@withoptionalarg}{\@without}` but with xparse you won't have to do that.

Comment: @PeterGrill It is ironic, is it not, that `\newcommand` doesn't follow that advice?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm sure that will be illuminating to somebody trying to grasp LaTeX's syntax.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Of course. But there's no reason that `\newcommand` couldn't be defined so that users of `\newcommand` used it with standard LaTeX syntax, rather than having to put the optional arguments in the middle of the mandatory ones.

Comment: @HenriMenke Oh wow. Very annoying that you can't assume standard syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The number and position of arguments is part of the command definition, so the order definitely matters.

`\documentclass` for example has two optional arguments, one before, and one after, the mandatory argument.

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}[2020/01/01]
```

for example would specify that you need a version of the class file no older than next year (this will generate an error that the version is not available, just so you see the effect).

so if you use

```
 \documentclass{article}[letter,12pt]
```

then you get an error not  because the optional argument is last, but because `letter,12pt` is not a valid date.

```
 \documentclass{article}[2000/01/01]
```

would work without error.

The basic `\newcommand` definition form only allows the definition of commands with a single optional argument, which appears first, however that restriction was just to keep the syntax of `\newcommand` simple, very few standard latex commands that have optional arguments are defined via `\newcommand`.

For a documented user interface that allows the specification of commands with multiple optional arguments in arbitrary position with respect to the mandatory arguments, see the `xparse` package.